# Angular Page Height Directive updating incorrectly

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am making a directive to set the height of a div equal to the height of the browser if the height of the div is less than the height of the browser.

I have created the following directive:

```
(function() {

var directive = function ($log, $window) {

    function evaluate(element) {
        var height = element.prop("offsetHeight");
        var pageHeight = $window.innerHeight;
        if (height < pageHeight)
        {
            $log.info("element height is less than page height, changing element height.");
            element.css("height", pageHeight);
        }
    }

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs)
        {
            //call it one time on load to handle first display
            evaluate(element);
            $window.addEventListener("resize",
                function() {
                    $log.info("Resize directive called: evaluating window size.");
                    //window size changed, check if we need to adjust the height
                    evaluate(element);
                });

            //add a watch to trigger when the inside of the div changes
            scope.$watch(function() { return element[0].childNodes.length }, function(values) {
                evaluate(element);
            });
        }

    }
};

angular.module('bootstrapApp')
    .directive('fullSize', ["$log", "$window", directive]);
```

})();

and it is used in the following way:

```
<body>
<fullsize-background-image-1></fullsize-background-image-1>
<navbar-1></navbar-1>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <left-sidebar-1></left-sidebar-1>
        <right-sidebar-1></right-sidebar-1>
        <div class="col-xs-12 main" id="main" full-size>
            <div ng-view="" autoscroll="true"></div>
            <footer-1></footer-1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
....
</body>
```

My problem is, on page load, thing was working perfectly (without the `scope.$watch` statement). However, when angular routed to a different page, that content replaced what is in the div#main element. Sometimes the height of the new page is greater than the height of the previous page, causing my hidden `<left-sidebar-1>` to show.

What I need to do is, on initial page load have my full-size directive evaluate what the height of main should be. Then, when the page changes, have it re-evaluate it and remove the property if the content is bigger.

thanks.